# Spring Data join list with where clause

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following Spring Data query:

```
@Query("from Release r join r.releaseProjects rp where rp.project.id = :projectId")
List<Release> getReleasesByProject(Long projectId);
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Release is a JPA entity with a List releaseProjects inside it.

Comment: There should be some more info (deep down the stack trace) telling what the exact issue with the query is

Comment: Since I do not know the details, I can not say for sure, but maybe try this: "SELECT r FROM Release r LEFT JOIN FETCH r.releaseProjects rp where rp.project.id = :projectId".